# Insert file records into postgres db using clojure jdbc is taking long time compared to python psycopg2

Tags: java, python, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I am trying to insert records into postgres DB, and its taking about 3 hours while it takes 40seconds using python psycopg2 and cursor.copy_from method

What is wrong with my code, using **clojure.java.jdbc/db-do-prepared** also takes about 3 hours too.
Please help!

File size is 175M and it has 409,854 records

```
(defn-
  str<->int [str]
  (let [n (read-string str)]
    (if (integer? n) n)))

(with-open [file (reader "/path/to/foo.txt")]
    (try
      (doseq [v (clojure-csv.core/parse-csv file)]

        (clojure.java.jdbc/insert! db  :records 
                      nil
                      [(v 0) (v 1) (v 2) (str<->int (v 3))]))
      (println "Records inserted successfully")
      (Exception e
        (println (.getNextException e) e))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 years, decided to come back to this problem and share a guide to the solution, I am sure this will help someone get started.

You can take a look at *clojure.java.jdbc/insert-multi!* and edit appropriately to suite the column types in your database

```
(let [from "/path/to/foo.txt"
      to "/path/to/temp/foo.txt"]
  (with-open [reader (io/reader from)
              writer (io/writer to)]
    (doall
      (->> (csv/read-csv reader)
           ;(drop 1)   ;if theres header
           (map #(list (nth % 0 nil) (nth % 2 nil)  (nth % 3 nil)))
           (csv/write-csv writer))))
  (let [fstream (slurp to)
        streamarray (map #(str/split % #",")
                         (str/split-lines fstream))]
    (clojure.java.jdbc/insert-multi! pg-db              ;connection or {:datasource hk-cp}
                                     :tbl_cdrs_da                 ;table name
                                     [:origin_node_type :origin_transaction_id :da_ua_id] ;colums
                                     streamarray)))               ;array
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably due to not using batching in your Clojure version. You insert rows one by one each triggering the commit.

If you want to do it in Clojure than you need to `partition` rows from CSV files and [`insert!`](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/insert!) each chunk as one batch commit. You need to use the last arity version accepting multiple `col-val-vec`s. Sample code (not checked, just to show the idea):

```
(defn row->col-spec [row]
  [(v 0) (v 1) (v 2) (str<->int (v 3))])

(with-open [csv-file (reader "/path/to/foo.txt")]
  (try
    (->> csv-file
         (clojure-csv.core/parse-csv)
         (map row->col-spec)
         (partition 50)
         (map (fn [batch] clojure.java.jdbc/insert! db :records ["col1" "col2" "col3" "col4"] batch))
         (dorun))
    (catch Exception e
      (println e))))
```

If you don't have to do it in Clojure then using [`psql`'s `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command seems to be the easiest and fastest option:

```
COPY records FROM '/path/to/foo.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',',  NULL 'NULL');
```

Comment: I'm using Clojure version 1.8.0, can you share an example of how it can be done in clojure

Comment: I have added a code example in Clojure - test it as I didn't run it.

Comment: Well, I used the PSQL Copy command you suggested, didn't even need to cast each field, this is indeed easier and faster. Thanks

Comment: What if I want to run the copy command as \copy, how will I go about it in clojure considering you can't do "\copy" when preparing the query string

Comment: @JobSam `\copy` is not an SQL command, it's a `psql` "meta-command" and it's not available via JDBC.

Comment: You are right. Then let me describe my problem to you maybe you can help if you don't mind. Running on clojure 1.8 and using clojure.java.jdbc I want to use the meta-command to copy a csv file. I can do (jdbc/execute! pooled-db-spec [(str "copy my_table from....)]) but not  (jdbc/execute! pooled-db-spec [(str "\copy my_table from....)]). Because I can't start a string with "\" (I guess this is more of a coding style). when I do "\\copy" the query is passed with the double quotes and thus it fails on the db. Your help/work around  will be appreciated.

Comment: As I wrote - you cannot use `\copy` in SQL statement. This is a `psql` meta-command and you would need to execute a `psql` binary and pass a script to it. That script would contain `\copy` meta command. But I think it would be better to post a new question describing what problem you are trying to solve as it's not clear why you want to use `\copy` instead of just SQL `COPY`.

Comment: Have a look too at https://github.com/jgdavey/clj-pgcopy